# discord bot on_guild_role_update, problem with permissions

Tags: python, discord, bots

I tryed to make logs with admin`s activity
how to specify the permission instead of these incomprehensible numbers

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_role_update(before, after):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xf04848
    )
    embed.set_author(name=f' Role `{before.name}` was changed!')
    if before.color != after.color:
        embed.add_field(name='Color:',  value=f'{before.color} --> {after.color}', inline=False)

    if before.name != after.name:
        embed.add_field(name='Name:', value=f'{before.name} --> {after.name}', inline=False)

    if before.permissions != after.permissions:
        embed.add_field(name='Permissions:', value=f'{before.permissions} --> {after.permissions}', inline=False)

    await bot.get_channel(911633362949648464).send(embed=embed)
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuQcP.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to determine the added or removed permissions and output it? discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097085/how-to-determine-the-added-or-removed-permissions-and-output-it-discord-bot)

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like

```py
if before.permissions != after.permissions:
    text = ""
    If before.permissions.change_nickname != after.permissions.change_nickname:
        text = f"{text}\n{'+change nickname' if after.permissions.change_nickname != True else '-change nickname'} --> {'+change nickname' if after.permissions.change_nickname == True else '-change nickname'}"
    #and so with all the rights and then just 
    embed.add_field(name="Permissions:", value=text, inline=False)
```

conclusion(if there was no right and it was given)

```
Permissins:
-change nickname --> +change nickname
```